# How to map a `Stream<Item=A>` into a `Stream<Item=B>`?

Tags: rust, rust-tonic

I'm using tonic and tonic returns a `Streaming<A>`, I want to turn it into a `Box<dyn Stream<Item=B>>`, so the user of my function don't need to know about tonic detail.

I tried

```rust
stream.map(|val| (turns A into B))
```

which gives me a `Map<Streaming<A>, |A| -> B>`, rather than a `Stream<B>` that I want.

Comment: You probably just want to make your function return `impl Stream<Item = B>`.

Comment: If you want it in a box, you need to call `Box::new`. Rust never implicitly boxes values for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, `impl Stream<Item=B>` does work. And yes I need to wrap the return value into a `Box`, I should've included a more concrete example in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stream<Item = B>` is a trait, not a type, so no value can be one. However, `Map<Streaming<A>, |A| -> B>` does implement `Stream<Item = B>`, which means it can be coerced into `dyn Stream<Item = B>`, which is a type. This trait object is put behind a pointer type (`Box` in this case) because it is unsized.

```rs
let new_stream = stream.map(|val| b(val));
Box::new(new_stream) as Box<dyn Stream<Item = B>>
```

It's likely you can leave off the `as` cast, since type inference will pick it up in most cases.

It may be possible to return `impl Stream<Item = B>` instead, which allows you to remove the `Box`. This hides the inner type from your public API.

Also note that [`TryStream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.26/futures/stream/trait.TryStream.html) and [`TryStreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.26/futures/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html) are useful for streams that return `Result` (they can be difficult to discover on your own). You should still return `impl Stream` or `dyn Stream` since those can be used as `TryStream`, but `TryStream` can't always be used as `Stream`. But you can use their methods inside your implementation.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out the answer is right there ;-) I'm just too used to the "map" in other languages. And as you said, the `as` cast is not needed.